# Woocommerce Shop page is still displaying old theme design

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used to have a theme installed and woocommerce page was displaying this theme's style I decided to try another theme but I changed my mind and restored it back to the old theme after applying a new one.
But the Shop page on Woocommerce is still showing the new theme style and wont revert to the original design.

I tried the following
1- clearing cache both on woo-commerce/status/clear template cache - on the browser and using clearing cache plugins with now use.
2- deleting and reinstalling the theme.
3- changing shop page to another one

Any resolution or advice are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear cache from your server and browser, if still, you can add a variable at the end of URL like `www.domain.com/?v=1`

Comment: Thank you so much the variable solution worked. Clearing cache did not work as well so I just added to the menu a custom link to the shop with a variable at the end of the URL and that worked.